# .gitignore blank in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, git, gitignore

Why is my `.gitignore` file blank in Windows (7) Explorer?

Note that both the `.htaccess` file and the `.git` folder appear as expected.

See:

[image]

Answer (score 16):

That is because Windows think that `.gitignore` is a file extension and hide the extension. And when there is nothing before the `.` its empty.

Here is an image with shows how to change it in the settings.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPYB8.png]

Comment: So why do .htaccess and .git appear as expected?

Comment: "for known file types" gitignore is a known file type and that because its hidden. and `.git` is a folder... thats only for files.